# Make Button disappear in the new row in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

This is the view of my datagridview..

[image]

This is the translate button when i click it a new row appears next to it and a new button is also initialized in that row.
[image: When the translation button is pressed]

Now what i want is that if the translate button is clicked the new row that appears shouldn't contain the translate button..i have initialized the button dynamically..Here is my code.

```
   private void button()
    {
        var buttonCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        buttonCol.Name = "ButtonColumnName";
        buttonCol.HeaderText = "Header";
        buttonCol.Text = "Translate";
        buttonCol.Name = "Edit";
        buttonCol.Width = 30;
        buttonCol.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(buttonCol);
    }
```

This is the event when the button is clicked..

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       // button();
        Column_handling();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 10)
        {
            DataRow dt = datarows.NewRow();
            dt[0] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            dt[1] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            dt[2] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dt[3] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dt[4] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            dt[5] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            dt[6] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            dt[7] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            dt[8] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            dt[9] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            datarows.Rows.InsertAt(dt, e.RowIndex+1);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change cell type to `TextBox`.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        Column_handling();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 10)
        {
            DataRow dt = datarows.NewRow();
            //fillign vlaues
            datarows.Rows.InsertAt(dt, e.RowIndex + 1);

            var row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1];
            var cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            cell.Value = string.Empty;

            row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"] = cell;

            cell.ReadOnly = true;

            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
}
```

I made cell `ReadOnly` to stop user from inputting anything into it.

Answer (score 0):

Button method pass a **boolean** field as parameter and set it false when you click Translate button to create row.
 Then set the `Visibility` property to this **boolean** field

set **default** value true otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know it is an old post, but anyhow... This is what works for me.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewButtonColumn) != null && dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        DataGridViewCellStyle emptyCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        emptyCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(75, 0, 0, 0);
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = emptyCellStyle;
    }
}
```